# Newtonsoft Json throws ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using the Newtonsoft Json library to handle Json strings.

I am currently in a project in which I have to receive a string from a RabbitMQ server. The string looks like this when I convert from the `RabbitMQ` response to the `JObject` found in the library:

```
{  "LoanResponse": { "interestRate": "12.768", "ssn": "811671177" }}
```

When I call the following code:

```
public AbstractDTO ToDTO(JObject jsonObj)
{
    BankResponseDTO dto = new BankResponseDTO();
    dto.InterestRate = jsonObj.GetValue("interestRate").Value<double>(); // <-- here is where it throws
    dto.SSN = jsonObj.GetValue("ssn").Value<String>();
    return dto;
}
```

I get the `ArgumentNullException`. With the following message:

```
{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}
```

It clearly contains an interest rate but it still tells me that it's null.
Anyone who might know what could be the issue here which i am facing difficult to find?

Comment: Either `jsonObj` is null or `GetValue("interestRate")` is null. Show us the values of `jsonObj` via debug?

Comment: I already did. The value of jsonObj is: {  "LoanResponse": {    "interestRate": "12.768",    "ssn": "811671177"  }}

Comment: Ahh, looks like the values are 2 deep (nested in `LoanResponse`). You'd have to get LoanResponse then from it get interestRate or ssn

Comment: @Vipar: Well then, `GetValue("interestRate")` is returning null, since there is no "interestRate" attribute on the object (only a "LoanResponse" object which in turn has an "interestRate").

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work now by first getting the JTokens in the JObject using LoanResponse as the index for GetValue()